# I lost my code; can I reconstruct it from the plot that is still in memory?

Tags: r, plot

I have a question about R. I think I forgot to save one of the scripts I was working on and I'm trying to get it back somehow. The script involved commands to create plots.

If I use the command:

```
print(nameoftheplot)
```

I am able to print the plot. Does this mean that R still has the script somewhere in the working memory? And how can I get it back?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That just means the plot "object" is still in memory - not necessarily the commands used to create it. Keep that session open, though! Are you using RStudio, or something else? RStudio, and probably some other IDEs, may have a history of those commands stored. Look for the "History" pane in RStudio.

Comment: Sometimes R also generates a ".Rhistory" file. If you use the `getwd()` function in your open session, it'll tell you what your current working directory is - and then you can check that folder for that .Rhistory file, which is just plain text with the history of your commands.

Comment: @Matt Dang, I completely forgot about that. I added something related to my answer but if you want to post your own answer I’ll remove it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No need, but thanks for checking! I just chucked out little tidbits as I thought of them - no time to compose a real answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to retrieve some of the code using the Rhistory file, which was already very useful.

Answer (score 5):

With luck, your commands are saved in R’s history; you should immediately perform

```
savehistory('history.r')
```

This usually contains all the last commands you executed.

---

> I am able to print the plot. Does this mean that R still has the script somewhere in the working memory?

Unfortunately, no. However, it still has the *print object* in memory, and you can dump that to retrieve some information:

```
dput(nameoftheplot)
```

Whether this is useful depends on how exactly the plot was created.

Apart from that, the following two things can give you information about the last state of your script:

```
ls()
```

will show you all the objects you defined in the global environment. You can look at their values for clues. In particular, if you defined functions, their code will be available in its entirety.

```
search()
```

will show you which packages your script loaded and attached.

From this you may be able to reconstruct large parts of your code.